# Is it possible to get an inventory of all physical hard disks on a linux server?

Tags: linux

Yes `fdisk -l` works but what if the disks were setup as a hardware RAID?

Comment: For things not behind a RAID, you might want to use something like `lshw -class disk` instead, since fdisk will show some block devices that are not actually physical disks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of hardware raid you would have to use a controller utility as provided by the manufactured of the raid controller.

Unfortunately there is no generic way to do it that would work with every HW raid vendor out there.

Comment: Hah you got me by 11 secs.  Oh well, I'll leave mine since it mentions specifics in case it helps the asker.  Still +1 for a correct answer first.

Answer (score 7):

The RAID controller vendor usually provides an interface to the disks behind it.  3ware has the 3DM web management and also a CLI utility.  Dell also provides this via OpenManage Server Administrator.  Not sure about other vendors, but I would imagine the same.

Comment: LSI controllers (including Dell PERC controllers) can be accessed with the MegaCLI program using "MegaCLI -PDList -aAll".

Comment: And HP raid is through `hpacucli`.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware RAID works by combining disks together and presenting them as devices on the hardware level.  There's no generic way for a linux machine to detect that and probe for the real disks behind the hardware raid.  However, most hardware raid devices come with some sort of linux utility program that provides info about the raid device.  If you find that utility for your particular raid device, you can use it to discover the actual disks attached to the raid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool named

```
 lshw
```

can do the trick.